# Dissect and explain this docker run command for cosmwasm

Tags: docker

could dissect this command and explain to me what this does?

```
docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)":/code \
  --mount type=volume,source="$(basename "$(pwd)")_cache",target=/code/target \
  --mount type=volume,source=registry_cache,target=/usr/local/cargo/registry \
  cosmwasm/workspace-optimizer:0.12.3
```

Comment: Which part gives you trouble? [--rm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#clean-up---rm), [-v](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems), [--mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)?

Comment: the --mount portions

Comment: Do you still have any specific questions after reading the corresponding portions of the documentation that I linked?